# How to launch hive with hive.cli.print.header=true in command line?

Tags: hadoop, hive

We know that to enable headers in results of hive query we need to do  **hive.cli.print.header=true** after going into hive.

Is there any way or command line argument by which we can launch hive such that default setting will be Auto Show Headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your home directory, you can create a file named `.hiverc`. For showing headers, add this line:
`set hive.cli.print.header=true;`